# Normal Reaction force

Tags: forces

I'm an elementary student, and I am told that the normal reaction force is always perpendicular to the surface of contact.

Please guide me as to how the normal changes in an accelerating frame AND when a frame moves with constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the normal force is,
F = mg + ma = m(g + a).

Here, a is vertical acceleration of the object. If the object is not in acceleration relative to the ground (observer's), then the vertical acceleration becomes zero and, therefore, F becomes equal to mg. If there is no acceleration then that means that the object is at rest or moving with constant velocity.
By knowing this above-mentioned concept one can calculate the normal force correctly.

Comment: okay thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In a frame with constant velocity it would be the same ([the laws of physics work the same in all inertial reference frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance)). In an accelerating frame the force would be displaced by the acceleration.